# Create User in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a user in the database. And I am using this stored procedure  to create it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspCreateUser
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN 
   CREATE USER [@Name] 
   WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]    
END
```

But when I execute my stored procedure with

```
EXEC uspCreateUser 'anny'
```

this creates user with `@Name` in database.

Can you please tell me how can I fix this?

This screenshot can help you to understand the question

[image: My database security folder -- User]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL. Generally, wherever the T-SQL syntax does not accept variable, dynamic SQL can provide the solution.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspCreateUser
    @Name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sqlstr nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE USER '+ @Name 
        +' WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlstr
END
GO

EXEC uspCreateUser 'anny';
```

You can find more information at:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/62982480-e7b0-4729-87a7-c0c6f27c7f45/create-sql-user-with-username-password-parameters?forum=transactsql

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic497615-359-1.aspx